# Closing Firefox Window or current Tab Using Java Script

Tags: javascript

How can i close a Firefox Window or current Tab Using Java Script? I tried the following code, but it doesn't work....

```
window.close();
```

Please anyone help me!!!!

Comment: your accept-rate is 0% - from the FAQ: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 2):

in JS, basically:

```
window.close();
```

or

```
self.close();
```

for more information, take a look at [this](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Close_Window_with_window.close_in_Javascript.shtml) and [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! I have used these code,but it doesn't work in Firefox (It is working fine in Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 1):

You only can close windows you have opened yourself and in most browsers the user will be prompted and ask for permisson, at least if the window has already a history.

```
var myWindow= window.open(address, "title", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
myWindow.close();
```